How can I set vector module parameter in ini file in OMNeT++
I would like to set the vector module parameters in ini file and I found I can not set in strings.
For example, this is the section of ned(ps. I defined a new mechost to move it dynamically):
mmecHost[0]:mmecHost{}

In ini file, I want to set the parameter
*.mmecHost[*].mecPlatform.numMecServices = 0
*.mmecHost[*].mecPlatform.mecService[0].typename = "LocationService"
*.mmecHost[*].mecPlatform.mecService[0].localAddress = "mmecHost[0].virtualisationInfrastructure" 
*.mmecHost[*].mecPlatform.mecService[0].localPort = 10020
*.mmecHost[*].mecPlatform.serviceRegistry.localAddress = "mmecHost[0].virtualisationInfrastructure" 
*.mmecHost[*].mecPlatform.serviceRegistry.localPort = 10021

Of coures, the "mmecHost[0].virtualisationInfrastructure" should correspond to the[*],but how can I achieve it.
The version of OMNeT++ is 5.2.6, sumo is 1.11.1, and veins is 5.2.
Thank you so much if you can help me.
I did not find a good way to solve this issue currently.
